# Calculate Parking Fees

Tags: java

Here's the description:

> Please write a Java Program for managing parking fees. each hour is
> $3.
>
> 1. The invoice has to contain: ID, amount, and subtotal.
> 2. The maximum fee of the day is $30, and give out a 5-dollar coupon.
> 3. The total parking Cars has to >0. If the entered cars is less than 0, the error message will show.
> 4. The total parking hours has to >0 and <24 hours. If the entered hours is incorrect, the error message will show.

This is an example of the output:

```
Please enter today's total parked cars: -3

The number you entered is less than 0, please re-enter: 0

The number you entered is less than 0, please re-enter: 8

Please enter your 1st car's parking hours: -1

The parking hours entered is incorrect, please re-enter: 25

The parking hours entered is incorrect, please re-enter: 30

The parking hours entered is incorrect, please re-enter: 24

Please enter your 2nd car's parking hours: 2

Please enter your 3rd car's parking hours: 5

Please enter your 4th car's parking hours: 9

Please enter your 5th car's parking hours: 4

Please enter your 6th car's parking hours: 3

----today's parking invoice----

ID.   Amount      Subtotal

1 _______30 _______ 30   *coupon

2 _______6 _______  36      

3 _______ 12_______ 48

4 _______ 3 _______   51  

5 _______30  _______  81    *coupon         

Today's total:$81
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tryagainparking {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Total parked cars:");
        int NUMBER_OF_CARS = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        while (NUMBER_OF_CARS<=0)
        {
            System.out.print("Cars has to >0，please re-entere：");
            int NUMBER_OF_CARS2 = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (NUMBER_OF_CARS2>0)
                break;
        }
        
        double hoursParked=0;
        double EveryAmount=0;
        int totalincome=0;
        int counter=1;
        
         
        for (int count=1;count<=NUMBER_OF_CARS;count++)
        {
             System.out.printf("this is the %d data:",count);
             hoursParked=keyboard.nextInt();
                while(hoursParked<=0)
                { 
                    System.out.printf("parking hour is incorrect, please re-eneter");
                    int hoursParked2=keyboard.nextInt();
                }
                while(hoursParked>=24)
                { 
                    System.out.printf("parking hour is incorrect, please re-eneter");
                    int hoursParked2=keyboard.nextInt();
                }
            EveryAmount=(hoursParked)*30;
                if (EveryAmount>=300)
                    EveryAmount=300;
            totalincome+=EveryAmount;
        
            
        }
        System.out.print("----invoice------\n");
        System.out.print("ID     Amount     Subtotal");
        
        System.out.printf("%s",counter);
    
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I encourage you to Extract Helper, and to separate mathematical business logic from I/O. Here's a simple way to motivate that: Go write a [JUnit](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests) test. Umm, you can't, right? The trouble is there is a single function, `main()`, and it is interactive. Your time would be well spent to write a failing "red bar" test, and then refactor so you see a successful green bar for each of your new helper methods, such as `public static double getEveryAmount(double hoursParked) {`

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Answer (score 3):

This test looks wrong:

> ```
>             while(hoursParked<=0)
>             { 
>                 System.out.printf("parking hour is incorrect, please re-eneter");
>                 int hoursParked2=keyboard.nextInt();
>             }
>             while(hoursParked>=24)
>             { 
>                 System.out.printf("parking hour is incorrect, please re-eneter");
>                 int hoursParked2=keyboard.nextInt();
>             }
> ```

In the second loop, we could enter a negative value, and that will be accepted.

And we want to *replace* the value we read earlier, not throw it away (we seem to have the same problem when we read the number of cars).

We want a *single* loop that repeats until *all* conditions are satisfied:

```
                while (hoursParked<=0 || hoursParked>=24)
                { 
                    System.out.printf("parking hour is incorrect, please re-enter");
                    hoursParked = keyboard.nextInt();
                }
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the text and also some other errors, and now I am stuck on the calculation

Answer (score 2):

*All code snippets assume that the 24-hour max is per car and that issuing a coupon has no impact on today's fees.*

### Data needs to be stored properly

A single piece of data should be stored in only one variable (like `NUMBER_OF_CARS` and `hoursParked`).

Conversely, data per car needs to be stored separately, not in a single variable that is overwritten.

```java
int[] hours = new int[NUMBER_OF_CARS];
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CARS; i++) {
    int carNum = i + 1;
    System.out.printf("Please enter car %d's parking hours: ", carNum);
    int hoursParked = keyboard.nextInt();
    while (hoursParked < 0 || hoursParked > 24) {
        System.out.print("Parking hours must be more than 0 and less than 24, please re-enter: ");
        hoursParked = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    hours[i] = hoursParked;
}
```

Using an array to track the hours per car has drawbacks, including that arrays are indexed from 0 and that no other data can be stored for each car here. The better solution is to create a `Car` object with fields like `id`, `hoursParked`, `charge`, and `coupon`, which can also encapsulate the charge & coupon logic.

### Do one thing at a time

For this program, the steps could be:

- Acquire inputs: get the number of cars and hours parked for each
- Calculate the charge: in a new array (`int[] charges`) or the `Car` object, calculate the charge for each car.

  ```java
  int charge = hours * 3;
  if (charge > 30)
      charge = 30;
  ```
- Generate the invoice: without significant refactoring, the subtotal will have to be calculated here.

  ```java
  int subtotal = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CARS; i++) {
      subtotal += charge[i];
      //print the car number, the charge, and the subtotal
      System.out.printf("%d  %d  %d", i + 1, charge[i], subtotal);
      if (charge[i] == 30)
          System.out.print("    *coupon");
      System.out.println(); //the next print statement will print to a new line
  }
  ```

Doing one thing at a time makes it easier to understand, verify, and test functionality. It also makes it easier to break the program into separate methods and objects with clear responsibilities.

*The included code snippets are simple examples and don't necessarily reflect best practices.*

Answer (score 1):

Your program has not implemented the requested functionality in at least one place: the requirements include ordinal formatting ("1st", etc.)

`eneter` needs to be spelled `enter`.

Java is basically a single-paradigm programming language; it strongly favours OOP over all else and your code is more procedural than OOP. You should practice making `Invoice` and `InvoiceCar` objects.

It doesn't make sense to print "re-enter" on the first iteration, when it's just an entry and not a re-entry.

Your input validation loop does do a range check, but does not do a field validity check. For this you need to catch an exception, and you also need to discard the rest of the line to avoid an infinite loop.

### Suggested

**Main.java**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (;;) {
            Invoice inv = Invoice.fromScanner(in);
            System.out.println();

            inv.print(System.out);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**FormatUtils.java**

```java
public abstract class FormatUtils {
    private static final String[] suffixes = new String[] {
        //0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
        "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th"
    };

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/6810409/313768
    public static String ordinal(int i) {
        return switch (i % 100) {
            case 11, 12, 13 ->
                i + "th";
            default ->
                i + suffixes[i % 10];
        };
    }
}
```

**Invoice.java**

```java
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public record Invoice(
    InvoiceCar[] cars
) {
    public static Invoice fromScanner(Scanner in) {
        int ncars = getCount(in);

        InvoiceCar[] cars = new InvoiceCar[ncars];

        for (int i = 0; i < ncars; i++)
            cars[i] = InvoiceCar.fromScanner(in, i + 1);

        return new Invoice(cars);
    }

    private static int getCount(Scanner in) {
        for (;;) {
            System.out.print("Please enter the number of parked cars: ");

            int input;
            try {
                input = in.nextInt();
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.err.println("Invalid integer");
                continue;
            }
            finally {
                in.nextLine();
            }

            if (input >= 0)
                return input;
            System.err.println("Number of cars must be at least 1");
        }
    }

    public void print(PrintStream out) {
        out.println("----Today's parking invoice----");
        out.printf("%3s %6s %8s %6s%n",
            "ID", "Hours", "Subtotal", "Coupon");

        for (InvoiceCar car: cars)
            out.println(car.invoiceRow("%3d %6.1f $%7.2f %c"));
        out.printf("%10s $%7.2f%n", "Total", total());
    }

    public double total() {
        return Arrays.stream(cars)
            .mapToDouble(InvoiceCar::subtotal)
            .sum();
    }
}
```

**InvoiceCar.java**

```java
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public record InvoiceCar(
    int id,
    double hours
) {
    public static final double
        rate = 3.00,
        maxCharge = 30.00;

    public static InvoiceCar fromScanner(Scanner in, int id) {
        return new InvoiceCar(id, getHours(in, id));
    }

    private static double getHours(Scanner in, int id) {
        String prompt = String.format(
            "Please enter %s car's park hours, greater than 0 and less than 24: ", FormatUtils.ordinal(id)
        );

        for (;;) {
            System.out.print(prompt);

            double input;
            try {
                input = in.nextDouble();
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.err.println("Invalid floating-point number");
                continue;
            }
            finally {
                in.nextLine();
            }

            if (input > 0 && input < 24)
                return input;
            System.err.println("Number out of range");
        }
    }

    public double subtotal() {
        return Double.min(maxCharge, rate*hours);
    }

    public boolean givesCoupon() {
        return rate*hours >= maxCharge;
    }

    public String invoiceRow(String fmt) {
        return fmt.formatted(id, hours, subtotal(),
            givesCoupon() ? '*' : ' ');
    }
}
```

```
Please enter the number of parked cars: f
Invalid integer
Please enter the number of parked cars: -3
Number of cars must be at least 1
Please enter the number of parked cars: 3
Please enter 1st car's park hours, greater than 0 and less than 24: f
Invalid floating-point number
Please enter 1st car's park hours, greater than 0 and less than 24: -3
Number out of range
Please enter 1st car's park hours, greater than 0 and less than 24: 3
Please enter 2nd car's park hours, greater than 0 and less than 24: 4
Please enter 3rd car's park hours, greater than 0 and less than 24: 18

----Today's parking invoice----
 ID  Hours Subtotal Coupon
  1    3.0 $   9.00  
  2    4.0 $  12.00  
  3   18.0 $  30.00 *
     Total $  51.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are my recommendations.

### Readability

My first recommendation would be to conform to a code indentation style.

The readability of code is important, and one of the best ways to achieve it is through consistent indentation, and format.

There are many different types of indentation styles.  *Wikipedia* offers an article on each.
*[Wikipedia – Indentation style – Brace placement in compound statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Brace_placement_in_compound_statements)*.

Textbooks typically use either *[K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#K&R_style)*, or *[Allman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style)*.  I recommend *K&R*.

Additionally, most *IDE*'s can automatically format code for you.

Also, Java recommends following a coding and naming convention.
Which is, typically, *"title case"* for object names, and *"camel case"* for member names.

Here is a PDF file, by Java, outlining a recommended pattern.
*[Sun Microsystems – Java Code Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/docs/tech/java/codeconventions.pdf)*.

### User-interface

The *UI* could be easier to understand.
For example, since the entered *"data"* is an hour value, the text should be similar to, *"hours for car %d:"*, etc.

Similarly, the output receipt should provide aligned values.
You can use the *[String#format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))* and *[String#formatted](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...))* methods for this; additionally, the *[Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html)* class.

### Control-flow

The *[control-flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow)* of the program *could* be improved, although, what you have is valid.

### Design

Try separating the content into different methods, and then calling the method—or methods—from *main*.

### Conclusion and example

The program contains no compile-time errors, just run-time errors, which are due to basic inconsistencies with semantics.
Overall, it's a great approach, and valid work.

Here is how I would write the same program.

```java
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TryAgainParking {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TryAgainParking tryAgainParking = new TryAgainParking();
        tryAgainParking.ui();
    }

    List<String[]> list;

    void ui() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String string;
        int totalCars = 0;
        boolean exit = false;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter total parked cars:  ");
            string = scanner.nextLine();
            if (string.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("No input.  Exiting");
                return;
            } else {
                try {
                    totalCars = Integer.parseInt(string);
                    if (totalCars <= 0) System.out.println("Amount must be greater-than 0");
                    else exit = true;
                } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input, try again");
                }
            }
        } while (!exit);

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        int hours;
        BigDecimal cost;
        exit = false;
        do {
            for (int count = 0; count < totalCars; count++) {
                System.out.printf("Enter hours for car %d:  ", count + 1);
                string = scanner.nextLine();
                if (string.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("No input.  Exiting");
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    hours = Integer.parseInt(string);
                    if (hours <= 0 || hours > 24) {
                        System.out.println("Value must be greater-than 0, and less-than 25.");
                        count--;
                    } else {
                        cost = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(hours));
                        cost = cost.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                        cost = cost.multiply(new BigDecimal("3"));
                        list.add(new String[] { String.valueOf(count + 1), String.valueOf(hours), cost.toPlainString() });
                        exit = true;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input, try again");
                }
            }
        } while (!exit);

        System.out.println();
        print();
    }

    void print() {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter(string);
        formatter.format("%s%s%1$s%n", "-".repeat(17), "Invoice");
        formatter.format("%-13s%-12s%s%n", "Id.", "Hours", "Sub-total");
        int id, hours;
        BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        for (String[] strings : list) {
            id = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]);
            hours = Integer.parseInt(strings[1]);
            formatter.format("%-13d%-12d$ %6s", id, hours, strings[2]);
            if (Float.parseFloat(strings[2]) >= 30) formatter.format(" *coupon");
            formatter.format("%n");
            total = total.add(new BigDecimal(strings[2]));
        }
        formatter.format("%s%n", "-".repeat(41));
        String value = "%33s".formatted(total.toPlainString());
        formatter.format("Total:  $" + value.substring(9));
        formatter.flush();
        formatter.close();
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Here are a few example input and outputs.

```
Enter total parked cars:  5
Enter hours for car 1:  1
Enter hours for car 2:  2
Enter hours for car 3:  3
Enter hours for car 4:  4
Enter hours for car 5:  10

-----------------Invoice-----------------
Id.          Hours       Sub-total
1            1           $   3.00
2            2           $   6.00
3            3           $   9.00
4            4           $  12.00
5            10          $  30.00 *coupon
-----------------------------------------
Total:  $                   60.00
```

```
Enter total parked cars:  0
Amount must be greater-than 0
Enter total parked cars:  -1
Amount must be greater-than 0
Enter total parked cars:  abc
Invalid input, try again
Enter total parked cars:  1
Enter hours for car 1:  100
Value must be greater-than 0, and less-than 25.
Enter hours for car 1:  0
Value must be greater-than 0, and less-than 25.
Enter hours for car 1:  -1
Value must be greater-than 0, and less-than 25.
Enter hours for car 1:  abc
Invalid input, try again
Enter hours for car 1:  
No input.  Exiting
```